# Which method is faster - foreach or LINQ selection?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am dealing with List collection. Which of the below will execute faster ?
Considering number of items in result as 1000.
**Method 1:**

```
var linqResult = from item in databaseObject
```

select item;

```
foreach(customobject item in linqResult)
{
List<customobject>.add(item);
}
```

**Method 2**

```
var data = from item in databaseObject
select new customobject()
{
//initialize properties
});

data.ToList();
```

Comment: Did you try to run the code?  What did you find as your results?

Comment: The database overhead is large enough that I suspect it'll be very close to the same. The latter _may_ be more efficient if you only want certain fields to be fetched.

Comment: @SLaks, why doesn't it matter? Performance nearly ALWAYS matters in software design?

Comment: It's just a theoratical question I think, with 1000 records it doesn't matter. You can write less code with linq.

Comment: @series0ne: And performance rarely matters in software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would suggest you unit/performance test your code to see which is faster for your particular scenario.
2. It depends on what exactly you are doing. My gut feeling is that a LINQ query (properly performance tested and optimized) will be faster than your run of the mill foreach loop.
3. LINQ-TO-SQL (which you have tagged), from what I understand, generates SQL commands based on your LINQ query, and runs these against the data source. This will definitely be faster that a foreach loop as the data source will return ONLY what you are expecting, as per the query, whereas the foreach loop would likely need to get the entire collection from SQL first, and then iterate over it.
4. If you are using In-Memory collections, you might want to investigate the speed of LINQ vs foreach vs Parallel.ForEach. Parallelism "could" perform faster than the equivalent LINQ, but again, you need to performance test all scenarios.

Comment: Notes: he or she should also try switching the order in tests (run foreach first and linq second, and vice versa). Also, regarding your point 4, there is also a [`.AsParallel()` LINQ method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel.aspx) that can be used instead of a `Parallel.ForEach`. Here's a great PDF article comparing the two: http://blog.mssoftwareconsulting.com/msswc/blog/file.axd?file=WhenToUseParallelForEachOrPLINQ.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think the benefits of linq selection, it provides you deferred execution while simple foreach not. If you use
 `yield return`

you can achieve what linq provides you by default.
I don't know is there any performance difference, but deferred execution can save you a lot of memory.